# Saving max, min mean median in a table through for loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
s<-NULL
for(i in seq(from=1,to=3360,by=240)){
  print(i)
  s<- rbind(s, data.table(
     max(mydata$duration_in_traffic[i:i+239]),
     min(mydata$duration_in_traffic[i:i+239]),
     mean(mydata$duration_in_traffic[i=i:i+239]),
     median(mydata$duration_in_traffic[i:i+239])))
}
```

I am trying to save max,min,mean and median in a table for various observations through for loop but it is returning the same value to max,min,mean and median in each observation.

[image]

Comment: You need to improve the formatting of your question, and take more time over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with `dplyr` package using iris data as an example:

```
iris$gp <- findInterval(1:nrow(iris), seq(1, nrow(iris), 40)) # create a grouping variable for every 40 observations of iris data

iris %>% 
    group_by(gp) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(Petal.Length), funs(max, min, mean, median))

# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#      gp   max   min     mean median
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1   1.9   1.0 1.460000   1.50
# 2     2   5.0   1.3 3.617500   4.15
# 3     3   6.9   3.0 4.902500   4.85
# 4     4   6.7   4.8 5.483333   5.55
```

In your case this should work:

```
s$gp <-  findInterval(1:nrow(iris), seq(1, 3360, 240))

s %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(duration_in_traffic), funs(max, min, mean, median))
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach by the way. It's just that you would probably need to create an empty data.frame with 4 columns (for max, min, mean and median) and i rows for the i value you are looping. Your current code will only give you the object s with based on the last i value of the loop, which overwrites the data.frame from the previous i values.

Comment: I am getting s for all the values, not just for the last value of i but the problem is that it is not able to read  'i' in the max,min function when I am putting values for eg.[1:240] its giving the right answer but not with [i,i+239].